# Javascript fetch() failover URL

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I have an array of URL's that I'd like to perform a `fetch()` request to:

```
const urls = [
  'https://dewnuf111111.com/configuration',
  'https://dewnuf222222.com/configuration',
  'https://bcsmania.co.uk/test.json'
];
```

If the fetch catches an error (e.g the site doesn't exist, internal error, etc), I'd like it to attempt the next URL, so I've added an incrementer.
Once it has reached a working URL and successully made a request, it should then simply `console.log('DONE')`, but I can't seem to get it working.

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
const urls = [
  'https://dewnuf111111.com/configuration',
  'https://dewnuf222222.com/configuration',
  'https://bcsmania.co.uk/test.json'
];

let obj = {a: 'test'};
let counter = 0;

function ajax(url) {
  // Check for for last URL in the array
  if (counter < urls.length) {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        // Combine objects
        obj = Object.assign(obj, response.json());
        console.log(urls[counter], obj);
        return Promise.resolve(obj);
      }).catch(error => {
        counter++;
        // Fetch next URL
        ajax(urls[counter]);
      });
  }
}

function getConfigurations() {
  return ajax(urls[counter]);
}

getConfigurations().then((configurations) => {
  console.log('DONE', configurations);
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g93qu26h/7/) to see a preview.

Can anyone shed some light as to where I could be going wrong?
Would I need to make the function `async` and then `await` the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean way to wait for first true returned by Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160260/clean-way-to-wait-for-first-true-returned-by-promise)

Comment: I think that duplicate candidate may be what you want.  I'm not sure if you want these to be tried sequentially and one at a time though (instead of all at once).

Comment: **return** ajax(urls[counter]);

Comment: @Kaiido - Ughr thank you so much. Can't believe I didn't see that. If you'd like to add your solution as an answer below, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I was searching for a dupe (there must be one already) but can't find it right now, so posted a CW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the Promise in your catch in order to be able to chain from it too:

```
.catch(error => {
    counter++;
    // return Fetch next URL
    return ajax(urls[counter]);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are mixing async code with sync code. Since your loop is sync in nature, It does n't wait for the result and once the code resolve it prints DONE. The simplest soln, u can use async-await in to loop url. I have given sample below. Please check.

https://jsfiddle.net/gof91e6v/

```
const urls = [
  "https://dewnuf111111.com/configuration",
  "https://dewnuf222222.com/configuration",
  "https://bcsmania.co.uk/test.json"
];

let obj = { a: "test" };

async function getConfigurations(urls) {
  let result = null;
  if (counter < urls.length) {
    for (let count = 0, len = urls.length; count < len; count++) {
      try {
        result = await fetch(urls[count]);
      } catch (e) {}
      if (result) break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

getConfigurations(urls).then(configurations => {
  console.log("DONE", configurations);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look to separate the fetching of a list of urls from how you handle it (e.g. your `Object.assign` call.)

In this version, `fetchFirstWorking` accepts a list of urls and responds with a Promise that will be resolved with the result of fetching the first live url.  Note that it uses recursion rather than a counter, so state management is kept to a minimum.

`getConfiguration` holds the business logic.

```js
const fetchFirstWorking = ( [url, ...urls], conf ) => url
  ? fetch (url, conf)
      .catch ( _ => fetchFirstWorking (urls) )
  : Promise .reject ('no urls could be loaded')

const getConfigurations = (urls) => 
  fetchFirstWorking(urls)
    .then ( res => res .json () )
    .then ( res => Object .assign ({a: 'test'}, res) )

const urls = [
  'https://dewnuf111111.com/configuration',
  'https://dewnuf222222.com/configuration',
  'https://bcsmania.co.uk/test.json'
]

getConfigurations (urls)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.warn)
```

If you replace the last url with another dummy, you will see it generate the console warning instead:

```js
const fetchFirstWorking = ( [url, ...urls], conf ) => url
  ? fetch (url, conf)
      .catch ( _ => fetchFirstWorking(urls) )
  : Promise .reject ('no urls could be loaded')

const getConfigurations = (urls) => 
  fetchFirstWorking(urls)
    .then ( res => res .json () )
    .then ( res => Object .assign ({a: 'test'}, res) )

const urls = [
  'https://dewnuf111111.com/configuration',
  'https://dewnuf222222.com/configuration',
  'https://dewnuf333333.com/configuration',
]

getConfigurations (urls)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.warn)
```